# Are there any Messianic references in the OT apocrypha?

Tags: life-of-jesus, apocrypha, messiah

Are there any references to Jesus / the Messiah in the OT apocrypha?

[(See example of book list here.)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_apocrypha#King_James_Version)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not part of my definition of apocrypha, but reading [Wisdom](http://www.usccb.org/bible/wisdom/2) leaves you with a distinct feeling that that the messiah is coming and he's going to be very badly treated.

I won't post all of Wisdom 2 here, but make sure if you read it, that you don't cut up the verses, these are bad people talking bad things about a righteous Man.

> For, not thinking rightly, they said among themselves:

(Wisdom 2:1 NABRE)

But, basically, [as some English monks point out](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=cZ5aYoSr3Hg), the entire Bible points to Christ in some way:

> In Tobit, He is the Messenger of New Life.
>
> In Judith, He is Weakness Turned into Victory.
>
> In Esther*, He is our Advocate.
>
> In 1 and 2 Maccabees, He is the Leader who dies for God’s law.
>
> In Wisdom, He is the emanation of God’s thought.
>
> In Ecclesiasticus (Sirach), Jesus is our security.
>
> In Baruch, He is the Mercy from the Eternal One.
>
> In Daniel*, Jesus is the Fourth Man in the fiery furnace.

*I know these aren't 100% Deuterocanonical, but they're in here for completion.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there are several ([Sirach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirach) and [Enoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Enoch) for example). In fact Jude quotes the book Enoch.

> **Jude 1:14-15**
>   14 And Enoch also, the seventh from Adam, prophesied of
>   these, saying, Behold, the Lord cometh with ten thousands of his
>   saints,
>
> 15 To execute judgment upon all, and to convince all that are ungodly
>   among them of all their ungodly deeds which they have ungodly
>   committed, and of all their hard speeches which ungodly sinners have
>   spoken against him.